How can I change the visited card button color or disabled button in google chat message card?
I'm using a PHP webhook URL to integrate Google Chat Space. I can successfully send messages using CURL, but I'm missing two things, and I haven't figured out how to get them.

How can I receive a response on my program if someone responds to a chat message? For example, if I respond to the conversation below, a fallback/callback URL will use the chat ID to call my server, allowing me to save the message there as well.
The action button will turn off or change the color if I respond to the chat message below, making it clear that something has already been done about it.

Chat space message 
Can someone please tell me how to fix this?
https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/create-messages

The question is a bit unclear but it sounds like maybe you need to listen for events in the workspace, so you can see when a message has been received - see https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/events-overview

I'm using a PHP webhook URL...it's unclear what webhook you are referring to. Can you link specifically to the documentation of the webhook you're talking about?

Thanks @ADyson, webhook means google chat space webhook URL, using this space URL we can send message using AJAX, CURL...

webhook means google chat space webhook URL...you already said this. But it's unclear what that means in terms of any of the documented features of chat space, which is why I asked you for a documentation link for the specific feature you're using. "Webhook" has a specific meaning and I can't help thinking that might actually not be what you're really referring to here.

Thanks @ADyson. I already mentioned the link. Please check https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/create-messages.

Ok. That's An API endpoint you can send requests to. It's not a webhook. A webhook means specifically where the API sends you a HTTP request in response to something happening inside the remote service. Hence my confusion when you referred to webhooks, because google workspace chat API doesn't have any documented webhooks. Its "events" feature is about the nearest thing - you can subscribe to an event and Google will send you notifications at a URL whenever that event occurs - it's almost the same process as how a webhook works really.

Okay @ADyson, Sorry for my wording. Now I want to change the color or disable the buttons  whenever I click on any button (https://i.sstatic.net/YjZwsbjx.png) Paid, Unpaid, Reject. Screenshot is from google chat space thread. Is this possible?

Not that I know of, sorry
